# Should I say "coming week" when it is weekend?

Tags: phrase-usage, time-reference

Today is Saturday and the date is May 8th. I want to say I'm available at 3 PM for all the days for the coming working days. That is for the date May 10 - May 14. Should I say: "I am available at 3 PM for all days in the ***coming/this*** week?" I am confused about whether I should use coming or this.

Comment: Both are fine; "coming" is possibly slightly better as it acknowledges that you're currently in the weekend; "this week coming" is probably how I'd word it. Were it Sunday then you might need to consider whether you consider the week to be already started (some countries start the week on a Monday, others on the Sunday). If there's any risk of ambiguity, I'd say "the week commencing 10th May".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I might use both: "I am available at 3PM each day **this coming** week." Or "each day this week starting Monday" (so they do not think you mean Sunday as well). But you could use either version alone and it would be fine.

You would say "in the coming week" but only "this week" (*not* "in the this week").